# NU1101: Unable to find package SVS.Build.No packages exist with this id in source(s)

Tags: nuget, scs

When we  were trying to create a build pipeline the scs project getting the below error

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) 

(NU1101: Unable to find package SVS.Build. No packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGetOrg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following source in the NuGet.config file with the developer collection feed and it would resolve the error.

`<add key="SVSComponents" value="https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-developer-collection/api/v3/index.json"/>`